# Testing gets in rspec (user input)

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

My class has this #run method that so far is just this, to test the testing:

```
def run
    puts "Enter 'class' to create a new class."
    input = $stdin.gets.chomp
    binding.pry
```

And in the tests so far I've got

```
  allow($stdin).to receive(:gets).and_return 'class'
  cli.run
```

Doing it this way I am able to see, in the pry session, that `input` has been set to `'class'`, as intended.

Is there a way to do with without adding `$stdin` to my call to `gets` in my method itself? i.e., `input = gets.chomp`

I've tried `allow(cli.run).to receive(:gets).and_return 'class'`
But then in the pry session, `input` is equal to the first line of the spec file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this as such:

```
def run
  puts "Enter 'class' to create a new class."
  input = gets.chomp
end

describe 'gets' do 
  it 'belongs to Kernel' do 
    allow_any_instance_of(Kernel).to receive(:gets).and_return('class')
    expect(run).to eq('class')
  end
end
```

The method `gets` actually belongs to the `Kernel` module. (`method(:gets).owner == Kernel`). Since `Kernel` is included in `Object` and almost all ruby objects inherit from `Object` this will work.

Now if `run` is an instance method scoped in a `Class` I would recommend scoping the stubbing a bit more such that:

```
class Test
  def run
    puts "Enter 'class' to create a new class."
    input = gets.chomp
  end
end

describe 'gets' do 
  it 'can be stubbed lower than that' do 
    allow_any_instance_of(Test).to receive(:gets).and_return('class')
    expect(Test.new.run).to eq('class')
  end
  # or even 
  it 'or even lower than that' do 
    cli = Test.new
    allow(cli).to receive(:gets).and_return('class')
    expect(cli.run).to eq('class')
  end
end
```

[Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/Stub-Kernelgets)

Comment: Thanks! `allow(cli).to receive(:gets).and_return('class')` is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, and it works.